# How to add description to a user control property in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I created one web user control with property named "ReadonlyField" with boolean datatype. I am able to use in my web pages and now I wanted to add a description to that property so that I don't need to explain each time to my team member what is that property's intention.

I got following snippet in c# but didnt find any equivalent in vb.net and also not sure whether it will work or not.

```
[Description("My Description")]
public int MyIntProperty
{
    get {..}
    set {..}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A literal translation in VB 10

```
<Description("My Description")> Public Property MyIntProperty As Integer
```

If this is for other programmers you may want to offer Intellisense support via XML comments. This is the standard way of doing it in both VB and C#.

VB

```
 ''' <summary>
 ''' Description goes here
 ''' </summary>
 ''' <value></value>
 ''' <returns></returns>
 ''' <remarks></remarks>
 Public Property MyIntProperty As Integer
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I was looking for the description to be displayed in the bottom status bar of the properties window. I tried <description> with System.ComponentModel and no error. But still i cant see the description in the properties window status bar :(. Do i need to do any additional steps to accomplish this?

Comment: Everything I've read says that you are doing it the right way. Maybe it's something stupid like you need to clean your project or even restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Even I tried all those restarting VS and rebuilding everything but till now it didnt work. Anyways i am using the remarks for telling the description. thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I put mine into the summary block, and then it shows in Intellisense...

```
 ''' <summary>
 ''' Returns "INSTALLATION ACTION INITIATED"
 ''' </summary>
 ''' <value></value>
 ''' <returns></returns>
 ''' <remarks></remarks>
 Public ReadOnly Property IAS
     Get
         Return _dict("IAS")
     End Get
 End Property
```